# Visual Studio 2019 'failed to retrieve information' when adding Nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, nuget, sqlite-net-pcl

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I'm attempting to add SQLite-Net-PCL to my project. However, when I go to "Project > Add Nuget Packages" and then select the SQLite package my console tells me this

> Getting restore information for project /Users/Me/Projects/TravelRecordApp/TravelRecordApp.iOS/TravelRecordApp.iOS.csproj
>   Getting restore information for project /Users/Me/Projects/TravelRecordApp/TravelRecordApp.Android/TravelRecordApp.Android.csproj
>   Running non-parallel restore.
>   Reading project file /Users/Me/Projects/TravelRecordApp/TravelRecordApp.Android/TravelRecordApp.Android.csproj.
>   The restore inputs for 'TravelRecordApp.Android' have changed. Continuing restore.
>   Restoring packages for /Users/Me/Projects/TravelRecordApp/TravelRecordApp.Android/TravelRecordApp.Android.csproj...
>   Restoring packages for MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1...
>
> GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/sqlitepclraw.bundle_green/index.json
>
> Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/sqlitepclraw.bundle_green/index.json'.
>
> An error occurred while sending the request
>   Error: SecureChannelFailure (Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket is not connected.)
>   Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket is not connected.
>   The socket is not connected
>
> GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/sqlitepclraw.bundle_green/index.json
>   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/sqlitepclraw.bundle_green/index.json'.
>   An error occurred while sending the request
>   Error: SecureChannelFailure (Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket is not connected.)
>   Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket is not connected.
>   The socket is not connected
>
> GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/sqlitepclraw.bundle_green/index.json
>   Failed to retrieve information about 'SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green' from remote source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/sqlitepclraw.bundle_green/index.json'.

I've tried adding older version of the package but I still get the same issue. Thank you for helping me

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/395584/visual-studio-for-mac-securechannelfailure-unable.html

Comment: Hi,Which version of VS2019,and version of SQLite.Net-PCL added is the latest(3.1.1)?

Comment: First of all, do not use `SQLite.Net-PCL ` as it not maintained by its author anymore what you should rather use is this https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/